# Can someone walk me through this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

```
(function($) {
  return $.extend($.fn, {
    link: function(o) {
      return $(this).find(":input").each(function() {
        var el, name;
        el = $(this);
        name = el.attr("name");
        o.bind("change:" + name, function() {
          // do stuff
        });
        return $(this).bind("change", function() {
          // do stuff
        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

There are a lot of functions inside other functions. My main questions (4 is what I'm trying to figure out through understanding this code):

1. What does it mean to extend $.fn and return that value?
2. What order is this code run in? If I put console.log as the first line in the each loop, I don't see it executed but I do see it if I put it in the "//do stuff" section.
3. If I'm inside the each statement and I look at the value of $(this).find(":input"), will that give me the values of the elements I'm currently looping in?
4. I tried to change ":input" to "p" but I'm still entering the "//do stuff" blocks on input elements. If I change the selector to add .filter or .not, I'm still breaking at the entering the "//do stuff" blocks when I don't think I should be- is this expected based on the order that everything is executed in? What if I wanted to only "//do stuff" if the element had a certain class?

Answer (score 1):

First, the outer-most function.

```
(function($){})(jQuery)
```

This creates an anonymous function, and immediately runs it.  It passes jQuery to it (as the `$`) parameter.

```
return $.extend($.fn, {});
```

`$.fn` is an alias for `.$.prototype` (or `jQuery.prototype`).  [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) merges multiple objects into the first one, then returns the first object.  Not sure why the `return` is there, it does nothing.

`$.fn` is how you add plugins.  This code adds a plugin called `link`.  It's called like:

```
$('.element').link($ele);
```

---

```
return $(this).find(":input").each(function () {
    var el, name;
    el = $(this);
    name = el.attr("name");
    o.bind("change:" + name, function () {
        // do stuff
    });
    return $(this).bind("change", function () {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

This is the actual plugin that gets ran when you do `$('.element').link($ele);`.

```
return $(this).find(":input").each(function(){});
```

The `return` is here for chainability.  So you can run other methods on the `<input>` elements.  Like: `$('.element').link($ele).val('test');`.

This plugin is binding some events, that's what `o.bind` does.  That `// do stuff` will only run when the `<input>` elements (and the element(s) passed in as `$ele`) are changed.

```
return $(this).bind("change", function(){});
```

This return is useless.  This is returning from the `.each`, which does nothing (`return false;` would be like a `break;`, but this always returns `true`).

---

NOTE: There is actually a syntax error in this code:

```
o.bind("change:" + name, function(){});
```

The colon (`:`) after `change` should be a period (`.`).  This is for creating ["namespaced events"](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/).

NOTE 2: This code probably doesn't do what you want it to.

```
o.bind("change:" + name, function(){});
```

This line is ran once per *each* `<input>` element, thus binding multiple events.  This may or may not be what was intended.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet: I have too much free time :-)

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a variable. It's a variable that is short, or an *alias*, for `jQuery`. It is simply, a reference to the jQuery object, or in other words:

```
var jQuery = { ... //All the jQuery code };
var $ = jQuery; //Where jQuery is a variable that contains the jQuery object.
```

So, understanding that, looking at `$.fn` you are looking at the jQuery object's `fn` property. Which is another object.

`$.extend(...)` is a method of jQuery, which combines all of it's arguments into a single object.

So, you are taking the `$.fn` object, and combining it with the object that is the second parameter in the above code:

```
{
    link: function(o) {
      return $(this).find(":input").each(function() {
        var el, name;
        el = $(this);
        name = el.attr("name");
        o.bind("change:" + name, function() {
          // do stuff
        });
        return $(this).bind("change", function() {
          // do stuff
        });
      });
    }
}
```

You are then returning that new, combined, object.

---

Your whole code is wrapped in what's called a closure, or in this case, a self-executing function. That is because you've defined an anonymous function, and told it to execute that function immediately.

Here's an anonymous function:

```
var anonFunction = function() { alert("hi"); };
```

Now, if you were to do:

```
anonFunction();
```

You'd execute that function and see the "hi" alert.

A self-executing, anonymous function takes this, and just calls itself, by wrapping itself in parentheses:

```
(function() { alert("hi"); })(); //Replace everything between the first set of `()` with `anonFunction` and you have the same thing as the last code example.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery API for .extend():

[$.extend() or jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

1. The code is executed in the order in which it is listed.
2. What you would probably want to do here is `console.log(this);` and it should result in a dump of the entire **this** object.
3. The `// do stuff` is actually binding a change event to element's *name*.

Why don't you try breaking down the script into smaller parts and examining what each of them do outside of their respective loop structures. The best way to learn is to toy around with it!

Answer (score 0):

This answer only talks about "when" the code is run. See the other answers for what it does or why it works, etc.

```
(function($) {
  // RUN WHEN the IIFE (Immediate Invoked Function Expression) is invoked
  return $.extend($.fn, {
    link: function(o) {
      // RUN WHEN plugin used - i.e. elm.link()
      return $(this).find(":input").each(function() {
        // RUN WHEN plugin used. Even though this is also a
        // callback, `each` will evaluate the callback
        // supplied synchronously.
        var el, name;
        el = $(this);
        name = el.attr("name");
        o.bind("change:" + name, function() {
          // RUN WHEN specific event later
        });
        return $(this).bind("change", function() {
          // RUN WHEN specific event later
        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery); // INVOKES the IIFE
```